# WSO2 AM2.0.0 monetization - Error wso2carbon.log:No schema is available for table ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have followed the article by @Ruks : [[Article] Enabling Monetization of APIs with WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-enabling-monetization-of-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/) and configured my WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 and WSO2 API Manager Analytics 2.0.0 with monetization. Billing engine is working fine. There are two issues:
Issue 1. When user is redirected from API Manger to billing engine for payment information, after successful signUp or login it does not redirect back to API manger.
Issue 2. On Analytics logs i am getting following error continuously

```
No schema is available for table ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-01-12T18:52:01.569122694Z"}
```

Please advise. what is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hi pravan, can you please mention the APIM analytics environment? is it cluster setup? and the DB used?.

Comment: Hi @ruks I am using WSO2 API Manager Analytics and DB is PostgresSql 9.5. Thanks

Comment: Its not cluster setup. it is single node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo to the sample billing engine provided in the article may not compatible with APIM 2.0.0. Please refer follwing [repo](https://github.com/chamilaadhi/wso2-am-billing-engine) and checkout am-2.0 tag which is compatible with APIM 2.0.0.

Comment: Thanks @ruks. I will try this repo and update you further on this.

Comment: Thanks @ruks. Issue 2  resolved >>Issue 2. On Analytics logs i am getting following error continuously No schema is available for table  ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST\r\n"   .. I am not getting this error any more in analytics server logs.   However Issue 1 still persists. please advise what i should do... >>Issue 1. When user is redirected from API Manger to billing engine for payment information, after successful signUp or login it does not redirect back to API manger.

Comment: Thanks Ruks again. Issue 1 also fixed, redirection works for all primary users but does not work for LDAP / domain users. I am trying to figure out what could be the issue. domain users are like xxx.com\user-id so not sure I have to create user on billing-engine in same format xxx.com\user-id.

Comment: Ruks, what should happen for existing users of billing-engine. when a api store user redirected to billing-engine for first time, user did a signup on billing engine and redirected back to store with active subscription. what should happen for user who already signed-up, even if users are already signed up, user is getting redirected to billing engine ... please advise.

Comment: @pravin, If user is already there APIM store will not redirect you to the billing engine.

Comment: yes. @Ruks it worked as you explained above. I noticed that. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that in the hosted version of API Manager - [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) - monetization just works out of the box because the engine has been pre-integrated with Stripe. You just enable the monetization feature in the Configure menu, set pricing for your tiers, and configure the Stripe account to send you the money. See the tutorial here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Enable+Monetization

Comment: Thanks but we are not using cloud version of wso2 API manager. We are using on-premise version of wso2 API manager.

Comment: OK, no worries. I just wanted to bring this as an easier solution in case this was an option.